# Indicators on how even the heat is distributed?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, heat

I'm wondering if there are any good indicators on how even the heat is distributed on an object (for simplicity, a flat object maybe)? What are the possibly reasonable ways to maximize the evenness if varying the shape of the object is allowed.

Comment: Are you asking about experimental ways to *measure* whether heat is evenly distributed, or theoretical ways to *define* whether heat is evenly distributed?

Comment: Statistically the longer you wait the more uniform the object will likely by.  If you're talking about a real-world object influenced by the environment then I suspect you'd need a supercomputer to model the heat flow over time with any significant accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

Heat is a process quantity, *not a system quantity*, and there is no indicator that you can attach to the object, but you could use a thermometer to record the distribution of temperatures of the object at different times and then infer the heat involved from some model (e.g. Fourier law).